# SSIS Script Task - Not picking any ddl

Tags: ssis, json.net, restsharp, script-task

Trying to add Newton.json & Restsharp in SSIS's Script task. But while adding I am getting a warning message also the script not working. An attached screenshot will add more points to this question.

[image: Error]

Comment: You have question blocks on your references.  There is something wrong with them.  Maybe they need to be refreshed or removed and added again

Comment: Did you maybe forget to add a `using` directive?

Comment: @TabAlleman I gave 'using RestSharp; using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;'

Comment: @brad where should I refresh the question blocks.

Comment: where the question blocks are right click on them and it should give you some options, I think one is to refresh/relink if it is bad.  If that does not work you can remove it and re-add the reference.  Assuming you did this originally so you know how to do it.

Comment: I have deleted & added again. But still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

These SSIS script projects are temporary, so anything you install via them (that is nested under them) disappears each time you exit the project.  Any third party .dlls need to be in a shared area and registered via gacutil and then the reference put in the temporary project instead of installed in the temporary project.